# Render component using a function did not work?

Tags: reactjs

Instead of throwing everything into one render function, I try to create function but it did not appear. What am I doing wrong?

```
var dashboard = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
           <div>
              <Datepicker /> 
              {this.renderDate()} //why this render nothing?
           </div>
        );
    }

    renderDate(){
      <Datepicker />
    }

});

module.exports = dashboard;
```

Comment: *"why this render nothing?*" Because `renderDate()` returns `undefined`, which basically is nothing. This has nothing to do with React btw, is is how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your renderDate method must return a component. Try this

```
renderDate(){
    return (
       <Datepicker />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the function `renderDate()` is wrong and lacked with a `,` before `renderDate()`, should like this:

```js
var dashboard = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
           <div>
              <Datepicker /> 
              {this.renderDate()}
           </div>
        );
    },

    renderDate(){
    return <Datepicker />;
    }

});

var Datepicker = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
           <div>
           Datepicker content
           </div>
        );
    }

});
```